# Rounded corners not working properly in IE while using CSS3Pie with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, css3pie

I am using jquery ui dialog and also css3pie for making border radius work in IE8.Following is the html code snippet that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.button.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function btnclick(){
                $("#confirmation").dialog({
                    resizable : false,
                    modal : true,
                    buttons : {
                        "Yes" : function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        "No" : function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-button {
                border-radius: 3px;
                behavior: url(pie.htc);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="btnclick()">Click</button>
        <div id="confirmation" title="Confirmation" style="display: none">
            Are you sure you want to Continue?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to give a border radius of 3px for the Yes and No buttons.When I open the popup first,the rounded corners are coming fine in IE 8.But When I again open it after closing this is what I am getting:

[image: Dialog error in IE]

Any idea how to solve this?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
        .ui-button {
            border-radius: 3px;
            -ms-border-radius: 3px;
            behavior: url(pie.htc);
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Just tried it.But unfortunately,that did not solve the issue.